# How to split a 2D array in different sized pieces for a crossword?

Tags: java, android, arrays, algorithm

I am experimenting with a generator for a crossword puzzle but I am getting stuck when it is time to split it up into different pieces. I have a 2D array where I store the crossword like this:

```
int SIZE = 10; //This can be higher for bigger crosswords
Character[][] crossword = new Character[SIZE][SIZE];
```

I then add a few words to this crossword and for example end up with the following array (. = empty square):

```
..........
..........
..C...H...
..A...O...
..TIGER...
......S...
...DOVE...
..........
..........
..........
```

How do I split this 2D array so that I end up with pieces that contains at least 2 letters but not a whole word. The letters must also be next to each other horizontally or vertically but not diagonally. For example I could end up with the following pieces:

```
C    TIG    H    ER    DOV
A           O     S
                  E
```

The following piece is NOT valid because the letters is not horizontally or vertically next to eachother.

```
  O
GE
  S
```

My first atempt to split this up was by doing the following:

```
int chunksize = 2; //This should vary depending on how big the pieces should be
List<Character[][]> subArrays = new ArrayList<>();
for(int i = 0; i < SIZE; i += chunksize){
    for(int j = 0; j < SIZE; j += chunksize){
        Character[][] sub = new Character[chunksize][chunksize];
        sub[0][0] = crossword[i][j];
        sub[0][1] = crossword[i][j + 1];
        sub[1][0] = crossword[i + 1][j];
        sub[1][1] = crossword[i + 1][j + 1];
        if(sub[0][0] != null || sub[0][1] != null || sub[1][0] != null || sub[1][1] != null){
            subArrays.add(sub);
        }
    }
}
```

However, this might create pieces that contains only one letter or pieces where the letters is not next to each other. I do not know how I should solve this problem which is why I come here for help.

Comment: What exactly is `chunksize`? Can you explain what you're trying to do with the nested for loop?

Comment: `chunksize` is my try to say how big the pieces should be. If it is 2 then I check the crossword 2 squares at a time, both horizontal and vertical. The nested for loop is there to loop through the rows and columns in the 2D array. However, this method (as it is now) will return pieces with wrong format and I do not know how to change it (or maybe just add more checks) to make it create pieces with the right format. The null chack at the end is a check to see if the created chunk (piece) contains letters or not.

Comment: Why do you exactly want to split up your array? I understand what is your problem but don't really see what do you want to achive with this.

Comment: I am trying to create a crossword puzzle generator. So if I have the completed crossword, I want to split it up into smaller pieces. These pieces is then given to a user that will try to fit all the words together. Instead of doing this manually I am trying to write a program to do it. For example, lets say we only have the word TIGER. Then I want to split it up into two pieces like this: TIG and ER. These pieces is then given to the user that will click and drag (or touch and drag if on android) to fit the pieces together and create the word TIGER.

Comment: So the `chunksize` is 2 for *ER*, and 3 for *TIG*?

Comment: Yes, but it should not always be a fixed number. It should adapt so the pieces follow the given format. It does not really matter if there are 2, 3 or more letters in one piece as long as the piece does not contain the whole word. The function I have given is just an example and I feel like it might not be the right way to solve the problem.

Comment: This sounds like a fun word puzzle, but I think some people are confused because what I call a "crossword" is different: you get clues (e.g., "A symbol of peace") for specific locations (e.g., "4 across").

Comment: Maybe you're right. The thought behind this is that you get one clue for every "crossword" and all the words have something to do with that clue. The clue for the example I have provided could be `Animals`. However, This is not something I am creating. I am just curious about how to "generating pieces".

Comment: Would a solution that creates as many size-2 blocks as possible be acceptable?  Depending on the layout, it might also create blocks of up to size 5, but in general there is no way to avoid these: consider 5 letters arranged in a "star", with a letter at the centre and each of its 2 horizontal and 2 vertical neighbouring positions containing a letter: there's no way to break this into smaller pieces without leaving at least 1 single-letter piece.

Comment: That is a situation that will not be allowed because as you say, there is not possible to split that up. Same goes for a 3 letter word that only matches on the middle letter. Replace the word dove with the word dog for my example. If this happen an error should occure. But if you have a solution that does not take this into consideration, I am happy to look at it

Comment: My approach basically creates as many size-2 blocks as possible, so afterwards, any remaining individual letters need to be attached to existing blocks as 3rd (or possibly 4th or 5th) letters somehow.  That can be done in various ways, but I can't think of a strategy that *rules out* the possibility that a size-5 block will be created.

Answer (score 0):

### Domino packing

The following approach creates as many size-2 blocks as possible.  Afterwards, any remaining individual letters need to be attached to a neighbouring block somehow -- e.g., by picking one of the neighbouring blocks at random.

Create a graph with a vertex for each position occupied by a letter, and an edge between any pair of vertically or horizontally adjacent letter positions.  Now compute a [maximum matching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matching_(graph_theory)#Definition) on this graph: this chooses a maximum-size edge subset such that no vertex is incident on more than one edge.  These edges correspond to the size-2 blocks.

If you imagine the grid as a chessboard, you'll notice that every square is either white or black, and no edge connects two white cells or two black cells: this means that the graph is bipartite, which in turn means that you can use the O(|E|*sqrt(|V|))-time [Hopcroft-Karp algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hopcroft%E2%80%93Karp_algorithm), which is faster and simpler than Edmonds's algorithm for general graphs.

Comment: I didn't understand a word, but ... WOW!

Answer (score 0):

What I would suggest you do is to convert each row and each column into a String of it's own.

eg:
First 3 Rows

```
..........
..........
..C...H...
```

First 3 columns

```
..........
..........
..CAT.....
```

You could do this by using for loops for example:

```
for(int x = 0; x < SIZE; x++){
    //Loop through rows and columns.
    //(eg:crossword[x][y] in this loop will extract a row of values)
    //(eg:crossword[y][x] in this loop will extract a column of values)
    for(int y = 0; y < SIZE; y++){
        //Code to build each row/column string
    }
    //Add extracted Strings to an ArrayList?
}
```

After you have these string you could split them by using: (Assuming . is still your deliminator)

```
s.split("\\.");
```

This will leave you with Arrays of the string from each row and columns

Extracts C and H as separate Strings from

```
..........
..........
..C...H...
```

Extracts CAT as a single String from

```
..........
..........
..CAT.....
```

This should allow you to check their length against chunksize and return the combinations you want.

Hopefully I have understood the problem correctly or it has at least given you some ideas that could be used to develop the solution you're looking for.